# SQL select ordered product quantities based on delivery date sorted by week

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure if my question is clear but what I need is quite complex query. I am unable to put it together myself.

We have tables `orders`, `order_items`, `products`, `deliveries` and `delivery_items`. Orders is the main order table. Order_items table holds the list of ordered products in certain order. Products is the main products table and deliveries/delivery_items tables hold the list of delivered order_items (we can deliver entire order or only partially).

This is the 'stripped down' table structure:

ORDERS:

```
ID    ORDER_NUMBER     DELIVERY_DATE    STATUS
-------------------------------------------------
1     2013-00001       Unixtimestamp    Closed
2     2013-00002       Unixtimestamp    Open
...
```

PRODUCTS:

```
ID    CODE
-----------------------
1     Product 1
2     Product 2
3     Product 3
...
```

ORDER ITEMS:

```
ID    ORDER_ID    PRODUCT_ID    QTY
-----------------------------------------
1     1           1             2
2     1           2             5
3     1           3             1
4     2           3             10
```

DELIVERIES:

```
ID    ORDER_ID    DELIVERY_NUMBER     TYPE
---------------------------------------------
1     1           2013-00001          Full
2     2           2013-00002          Partial
...
```

DELIVERY_ITEMS:

```
ID    DELIVERY_ID     ORDER_ITEM_ID    QTY
------------------------------------------
1     1               1                2
2     1               2                5
3     1               3                1
4     2               4                5
...
```

Our production demands view where all non-delivered order_items(products) are listed by quantities in the upcoming week schedule. What I need is something like this (quantities here are random):

```
Product     Overdue    W0    W1    W2    W3    W4    W5    Later    Total
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product 1   1          2     0     0     0     0     0     0        3
Product 2   0          3     5     1     0     0     0     4        13
Product 3   2          4     0     7     5     0     0     0        18
...
```

The entire view is based on current time and order's delivery_date field. The query would need to get ordered product quantities from all open orders, check if some of there products were maybe already delivered and subtract delivered quantities, and on the end sort the result quantities as shown above.

UPDATE: here is SQL Fiddle with above structure with some data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88891/4

Comment: In deliveries table order_id 1 has type full, I guess this means it's been delivered. Yet it has status open in orders table. Also there seems to be no column to indicate which items of each order might have already been delivered and which not. There's just column type = full/partial which is basically useless. Also post what you've tried. This is not a "we do the work for you" site. And you won't learn to do it yourself if you don't at least try to do it yourself.

Comment: and use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create a basic schema with some values

Comment: You are correct regarding delivered order, it was my mistake. That order should be marked closed and all product quantities of that ignored in the final view. I have corrected in my question.  Regarding the indication which items have already been delivered. What important are only the desired delivered quantities, and that can be read trough 'delivery_items' table, which is also linked to 'order_items'.

Comment: @VeNoMiS ok I will create sqlfiddle

Comment: @VeNoMiS SQL Fiddle added

Comment: why did I get - for this question?

Comment: Likely because it showed no SQL in the query with what you attempted.  many people don't want to "Do the work for you" they want to "help you with what you have done so far"  This is more about teaching and educating which can't be done w/o effort.  The fact you put the fiddle together showed me you were trying...

Comment: Sure I understand and agree to that. I would supply a query if I had one. Been trying build a query myself for some time now but always ended up with a strategy that leaded to a dead end. I've got to learn from your answer and I will.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html may help with your understanding of left/right/inner/ cross joins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---Using Fiddle provided (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88891/34/0)

```
SELECT P.Name,
sum(case when DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())<=0 then coalesce(OI.Quantity,0)-coalesce(DI.Quantity,0) else 0 END) AS Overdue,
sum(case when DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())<=7 and DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())>0  then coalesce(OI.Quantity,0)-coalesce(DI.Quantity,0) else 0 END) as W0,
sum(case when DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())<=14 and DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())>7  then coalesce(OI.Quantity,0)-coalesce(DI.Quantity,0) else 0 END) as W1,
sum(case when DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())<=21 and DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())>14 then coalesce(OI.Quantity,0)-coalesce(DI.Quantity,0) else 0 END) as W2,
sum(case when DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())<=28 and DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())>21 then coalesce(OI.Quantity,0)-coalesce(DI.Quantity,0) else 0 END) as W3,
sum(case when DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())<=35 and DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())>28 then coalesce(OI.Quantity,0)-coalesce(DI.Quantity,0) else 0 END) as W4,
sum(case when DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())<=42 and DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())>35 then coalesce(OI.Quantity,0)-coalesce(DI.Quantity,0) else 0 END) as W5,
sum(case when DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(Delivery_date),curDate())>42 then coalesce(OI.Quantity,0)-coalesce(DI.Quantity,0) else 0 END) as Later,
sum(coalesce(OI.Quantity,0)-coalesce(DI.Quantity,0)) as Total

FROM ORDERS O
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS OI
  ON OI.Order_ID = O.ID
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS P on 
  P.ID = OI.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN DELIVERIES D
  ON D.Order_ID = O.ID
LEFT JOIN DELIVERY_ITEMS DI
  ON DI.Delivery_ID = D.ID
  AND OI.ID = DI.Order_Item_ID
WHERE coalesce(DI.Quantity,0) < OI.Quantity 
GROUP BY P.Name
```

Thanks for the fiddle.  This takes care of all the remaining syntax errors. and formats to include 0 in the results.

- Coalesce, takes first non-null value in an unlimited series.
- FROM_UNIXTIME converts into to valid date time for comparison using datediff.
- else statments handle situations when no data matches critiera thus 0 is
  evaluated.
- where clause eliminates orders with all items delivered or more than all items ordered delivered. (Thus items closed will still be included since they are not fully shipped!)

Comment: W0 is current week, W1 is next week and so on... Overdue are the orders that delivery date is already in the past...

Comment: Delivered item count can never be > then ordered item count... It's just impossible.

Comment: Corrected logic again due to compounding error on products being included in weeks following due date.  Logically, I think this is correct.  It may have a few syntax errors however. And there may be a faster way to do this with Analytic functions; or perhaps a subquery to get the date difference first instead of doing the calculations over and over.

Comment: There is a syntax error I can't fix > You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(case WHEN DATEDIFF...

Comment: I think `case_value` is missing after case...? From case syntax docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: @PrimozRome updated using fiddle provided.  note NULLs are returning on some of the SUMs.. I need to look into it but I believe it's on the math parts I need to coalesce all values incase the left join has no records.

Comment: Wow looking good, I'm not bother with null's since I can replace them with 0 on app-side... If the logic works properly then this is sure the best solution I have until now

Comment: Should I put where orders.status = 'Opened' so I could skip all closed orders?

Comment: That's up to you.  The Original Post (OP) didn't indicate to evaluate order status.  This simply looks at ALL ordered_items against the delivered items and reports on ones which are not fulfilled.  If an order is "closed" but not fully shipped do you want it to show up?  if you do then don't put status='Opened', otherwise do.  It also depends on if you have other status for order besides open and closed...  Who said this stuff was easy?

Comment: Great, I will accept this answer after I do some more testing. Thanks

Comment: Hi again. After some time in production use I found a bug in your query, which I am unable to fix. It only occurs in this situation: When the quantities of the same order_item are spread over 2 or more deliveries, then the calculated difference between non-delivered and delivered quantities is wrong, because the overall order_item quantities are multiplied by the number of deliveries that this order_item is on. I have created SQL fiddle showing this situation http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7b9e/4. I hope you can understand why this bug happens.

Comment: take a look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7b9e/13/0  it shows that the delqty is perhaps what we need to sum and not just quantity.  I'll have to look at this in more detail after I've had some sleep though.  It shows shows the sum of qty may have been on the ordered qty and not the delivered qty... which could be causing problems elsewhere. but again, I need some sleep so I may be totally off here.

Comment: Hmm we do need to sum all delivered qtys, that's for sure, but we already do this? I think the problem is when we sum up the delivered qtys we also multiply qtys from the order that these deliveries derive from and therefore the difference between order qtys and delivered qtys is not correct anymore...

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, here are a couple of joins:

```
SELECT o.ORDER_NUMBER, p.CODE, oi.QTY
FROM orders o
JOIN order_items oi ON oi.ORDER_ID = o.ID
JOIN products p ON p.ID = oi.PRODUCT_ID
```

And:

```
SELECT d.DELIVERY_NUMBER, d.ORDER_ID, di.ORDER_ITEM_ID, di.QTY
FROM deliveries d
JOIN delivery_items di ON di.DELIVERY_ID = d.ID
```

What would you have to do to tie those together?